# Display an zero-count row in pivot table

Tags: oracle, pivot, aggregate

I would like to display 2 pivot table using aggregate function, 1 displaying the actual count (including row with zero-count) and 1 displaying the percentage (including row with zero-count)

The data is currently stored in the following format

```
Mode    Occupation  Year
FT  Employed    2016
FT  Employed    2015
PT  Employed    2017
PT  Employed    2017
PT  Employed    2017
```

I would like to display the data into

```
          2015  2016 2017
FT Study    0     0   0
PT Study    0     0   0
FT Employed 1     1   0
PT Employed 0     0   3
```

and

```
           2015 2016 2017
FT Study    0     0   0
PT Study    0     0   0
FT Employed 20%   20% 0
PT Employed 0     0   60%
```

My sql is

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT TESTING, YEAR FROM(
select MODE||' '||OCCUPATION AS TESTING, b.* from TABLE 1 b
)) 
PIVOT
(COUNT(YEAR )
FOR YEAR IN ('2015', '2016', '2017'))
```

However The record of PT Study cannot be displayed since there is no record of 'PT Study', moreover no table contain the full list of 'Occupation', is there any way I can compose this pivot table without creating a table of the full list of 'Occupation'.

Thank you so mush for your help!

Comment: If there's no table of occupations how do you know what values are missing and need to be filled in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CTE ([subquery factoring](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__I2077142)) to generate a list of all possible occupations - in this case it seems to need to be a hard-coded list; and you could add one for the modes too to be safe. Then cross-join the possible modes and occupations, and outer join to you actual table to get the numbers:

```
with emp_modes (emp_mode) as (
  select 'PT' from dual
  union all select 'FT' from dual
),
occupations (occupation) as (
  select 'Employed' from dual
  union all select 'Study' from dual
)
select * from(
  select e.emp_mode||' '||o.occupation as testing, b.year
  from emp_modes e
  cross join occupations o
  left join table1 b on b.emp_mode = e.emp_mode and b.occupation = o.occupation
) 
pivot (
 count(year) for year in (2015, 2016, 2017)
)
order by testing

TESTING           2015       2016       2017
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------
FT Employed          1          1          0
FT Study             0          0          0
PT Employed          0          0          3
PT Study             0          0          0
```

I've changed `mode` to `emp_mode` as the former is a reserved word.

If there are actual records for `Study` then you'll see the real counts; if there are not then the outer join means you'll still see a zero count.

For the duration of the query the `occupations` CTE behaves as if you did have an actual table, without having to create one. You do have to maintain the hard-coded list as part of the query though, so a permanent table is probably more practical, unless the list of possible occupations can be generated from other data. (Sometimes you can query the actual table in the CTE to get all possible values; in this case as there is no filter on year that doesn't help, but perhaps it does in your real data).

Answer (score 0):

You could add extra lines for Pt study and FT study with `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT TESTING, YEAR
          FROM (SELECT MODE_T || ' ' || OCCUPATION AS TESTING, b.*
                  FROM TABLE1 b)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'PT Study' AS TESTING, NULL year
          FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'FT Study' AS TESTING, NULL year
          FROM DUAL) PIVOT (COUNT (YEAR)
                     FOR YEAR
                     IN ('2015', '2016', '2017'));
```